# The website is auto reloading automatically

Tags: wordpress, cookies, reload, page-refresh

I have a problem with a website made on Wordpress. The website is reloading automatically as soon as you hit enter to get on the website. Apparently it's a problem with the cookies, or so. After some hits on the F5 button it works and keeps working. If I delete the cookies, it starts to refresh again if I try to enter on the website. Did you encountered this type of problem? You can see it [here](http://newhackdld.com)

Comment: How we supposed to help if we don't get a url, code or some relevant information? Example: Which Plugins you installed or Themes?

Comment: @CagatayUlubay I edited my post, sorry.

Comment: Have you seen this in your source code? `<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
document.cookie='tttv=154794; domain=newhackdld.com; path=/';document.location='/';
// -->
</SCRIPT>Loading... </body>` It seems like it's always changing the `window.location.path` to `/` which is the base domain

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/ | Seems like SEO friendly URL settings are messing your page up